# Building a templated ODE solver

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to implement a templated ODE solver with the following function declaration:

```
template<class ODEFunction,class StopCondition=decltype(continue_always<ODEFunction>)> 
bool euler_fwd(ODEFunction& f,typename State<ODEFunction>::type& x_0
    ,double t_0,double dt,size_t N_iter
    ,StopCondition& cond=continue_always<ODEFunction>);
```

The full source:

```
/*From SO answer*/

template<class F>
struct State;

template <class R, class... A> 
struct State<R (*)(A...)>
    {
    typedef R type;
    };

/*End from SO answer*/


/**Default stop condition. Always return 0 to continue operation.
*/
template<class ODEFunction>
bool continue_always(const typename State<ODEFunction>::type& x_0,double t_0)
    {return 0;}

/**Euler forward solver
*/
template<class ODEFunction,class StopCondition=decltype(continue_always<ODEFunction>)> 
bool euler_fwd(ODEFunction& f,typename State<ODEFunction>::type& x_0
    ,double t_0,double dt,size_t N_iter
    ,StopCondition& cond=continue_always<ODEFunction>)
    {
    size_t k=0;
    while(N_iter)
        {
        if(cond(x_0,t_0))
           {return 1;}
        x_0+=dt*f(x_0,k*dt);
        --N_iter;
        ++k;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

trying to call euler_fwd with a simple function

```
double f(double x,double t)
    {return x;}
```

omitting the continue_always predicate, GCC writes

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct State'
>      bool continue_always(const typename State::type& x_0,double t_0)

...

> test.cpp:18:47: error: no matching function for call to 'euler_fwd(double (&)(double, double), double&, double&, double&, size_t&)'

EDIT:

If I try to skip the use of default argument for cond:

```
euler_fwd(testfunc,x_0,t_0,dt,N,continue_always<decltype(testfunc)>);
```

I still get an error

> test.cpp:18:97: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function 'continue_always'

Comment: One possible way to solve this problem is to write `template <class R, class... A> struct State<R(A...)>` instead of `template <class R, class... A> struct State<R (*)(A...)>`.

Comment: @Constructor If ODEFunction is a function object instead of a function pointer, is it possible to define the non-specialized State struct so the function object does not need to contain a typedef for the return type of its function operator?

Comment: Typical solution here is to use `decltype`: `decltype(f(/* ... */))`. But in this case it is not possible (so simply at least) because `decltype(f(a, b)) == decltype(a)` as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to manipulate the function types (types of `f`, `cond`), why not make the state a template argument?

```
#include <cstdlib> // for size_t
#include <functional>

template<class R>
bool continue_always(const R& x_0,double t_0)
{return 0;}

template<class R> 
bool euler_fwd(std::function<R(const R &)> f,R& x_0
  ,double t_0,double dt,size_t N_iter
  ,std::function<bool(const R&, double)> cond=continue_always<R>)
{
  size_t k=0;
  while(N_iter)
  {
    if(cond(x_0,t_0))
      {return 1;}
    x_0+=dt*f(x_0,k*dt);
    --N_iter;
    ++k;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type is R(const R&). Never seen that syntax before

Comment: `std::function<R(const R&)>` is the type of a callable object that takes a `const R&` and returns an `R`.  Take a look at the documentation for `std::function`.

Comment: I referred to the type parameter that is given to that template.

Comment: It is type type of a function (vs a function pointer).  For example, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027922/intint-int-style-template-function-type-syntax